# Angularjs resizing overlayed on div's on img-responsive

Tags: angularjs, resize, angular-directive

http://plnkr.co/edit/mQb85ejjxzHOL5Vkv4Ua?p=preview

I do have a bootstrap img-responsive element with overlayed div elements. How can resize these divs by binding the width and height attributes. I do not want to use jquery, do it the correct angular way.

I have tried with this directive

```
            App.directive('onSizeChanged', ['$window', function ($window) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    scope: {
                        onSizeChanged: '&'
                    },
                    link: function (scope, $element, attr) {
                        var element = $element[0];

                        cacheElementSize(scope, element);
                        $window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

                        function cacheElementSize(scope, element) {
                            scope.cachedElementWidth = element.offsetWidth;
                            scope.cachedElementHeight = element.offsetHeight;
                        }

                        function onWindowResize() {
                            var isSizeChanged = scope.cachedElementWidth != element.offsetWidth || scope.cachedElementHeight != element.offsetHeight;
                            if (isSizeChanged) {
                                var expression = scope.onSizeChanged();
                                expression();
                            }
                        };
                    }
                }
            }]);
```

but somehow I am not able to update the width of my elements

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to disappoint you after you tried to work out that directive, but the best way to actually do this is with CSS:

## [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qA5vpePGsYmAQYDZAljI?p=preview)

Simply change your overlays to use percentages and they will always automatically stay in the right proportion and position:

```
#overlay1{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;  
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 65%;
    bottom: 65%;
}
#overlay2{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;  
    top: 35%;
    left: 35%;
    right: 35%;
    bottom: 35%;
}
#overlay3{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;  
    top: 65%;
    left: 65%;
    right: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
}
```